# Internal working of GAE Search API (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to know how the Search API store `Document` internally? Does it store a `Document` into the Datastore with a "Document" kind? Or something else? Also where are indexes stored? In memcache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents and indexes are stored in HR Datastore

> Documents and indexes are saved in a separate persistent store
>   optimized for search operations
>
> The Document class represents documents. Each document has a document identifier and a list of fields.
>
> The Document class represents documents. Each document has a document identifier and a list of fields.

It's all in Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/#Java_Documents_and_fields)